# How to Solve : Value Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Shuk'?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

**Hello  , so i have been realy struggling with that problem when trying to list all Animes Objects on my Database (api)**

```
class AnimesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    queryset            = Animes.objects.all()
    serializer_class    = AnimesSerializer


    @action(methods=['get'],detail=False)
    def types(self,request):
        return Response(getTypes())


    @action(methods=['get'],detail=False)
    def _action(self,request):
        li = Animes.objects.all().filter(types__icontains='action')
        result_list =  li.values('id', 'title', 'coverLink', 'yearProd', 'rates', 'types', 'story') 
        return Response(result_list)
```

when visiting :

- localhost:8000/api/animes/types/ => this works fine !
- localhost:8000/api/animes/_action/ => this works fine !
- localhost:8000/api/animes/**id**/ => (dynamic anime id 1..2..3..etc) this works fine !
- **localhost:8000/api/animes/** => this Does not work (shows the problem im having) !

**serializer.py :**

```
class AnimesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model   = Animes
    fields  = ('id', 'title', 'coverLink', 'yearProd', 'rates', 'types', 'story')
```

**router.py :**

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import AnimesViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('animes', AnimesViewSet, 'animes')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

**models.py :**

```
class Animes(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()
  animePageLink = models.TextField()
  pageNum = models.IntegerField()
  coverLink = models.TextField()
  yearProd = models.IntegerField()
  rates = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=1)
  types = models.TextField(null=True)
  story = models.TextField()

  def types_to_list(self):
    return self.types.split(',')
```

**urls.py :**

```
    path('api/',include('animes.router')),
```

**Example of single Instance of Animes :**

```
{"id":2,"title":"Mo Dao Zu Shi","coverLink":"https://xxx/test.jpg","yearProd":2018,"rates":"8.6","types":"action,adventure,historical,mystery,supernatural,comedy","story":"test story..."}
```

I have Tried so many solutions by people who had same problems on **stackoverflow**  but none of them realy worked for me !

**PS : im still new at Django and Rest Framework too**
~ Thank you !

Comment: your code is fine  it should work may be the issues with IntegerField for this your passing string number(like "1") while saving instead of Integer (like 1)

Comment: Seems like your code does `int( 'Shuk' )` ...

Comment: agreed the pasted code looks valid. You probably strip some part of the viewset or of the serialiser that is leading to the issue you have.

Comment: @giveJob huh ? You mean like ... i wrongly stored "1" as string in a IntegerField() ? 
Well the insertion of DATAS i ve done it  with an extern py script that i made (get from my old api and store to db ) .. can you please explain more ?

Comment: What I'm telling is you are trying to to add string in the field of integer like this Seems like your code does int( 'Shuk' )

Comment: @giveJob i mean yeah i get that already searched and got that part , but what i realy dont understand is to actualy fix this ?

I typed every single piece of code by my  fingers , I just dont know where that exact problem comming from so i can fix it i still dont know yet !

So i would love if you guys can point me on How to actually fix that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright , I solved the problem !
Basically i changed the return on field.py in IntegerField Class to return value instead of int(value) .. So i figured that this is something from the database that is expected to be int but its not !

when i checked i found that one of my anime instances had : "Shuk" as a **yearProd** which is expected to be of type int , well the main problem was because i forgot to check if the value is int or not when i was  inserting my datas externally so solved it by simply changing the field type in my models :

```
yearProd = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

Hopefully this will be usefull to some1 in future .
Thanks alot !